# Shell script : sed command is ignoring INFO lines given main 2>&1

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, program-entry-point

`main 2>&1` is giving INFO, ERROR and Running status lines.
But when I use sed on it, it is giving INFO and Running status lines along with ERROR lines but they are not in the order where they have to.

[Jumbled status are at the end after job executed succefully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjJGO.png).

```
main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stderr)/ s/ERROR/NOTE/" | tee -a $log_file
```

These are the lines which are missing after I use sed command:[image]

Comment: Would be better if you can add textual input to your question. And please state your question with more details (what is that you are trying to do).

Comment: Post the text itself, not a link to an image of the text.

Answer (score 0):

if you append `/\(Running\|INFO\ERROR...` in sed as below, this can also print Running and info along with ERROR lines

```
main 2>&1 | sed "/\(Running\|INFO\|ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stderr)\)/ s/ERROR/NOTE/" | tee -a $log_file
```

Comment: It is not working. It is just repeating existing status lines in the log file.

Comment: Even now the results are same.
The lines placed randomly (somewhere in the middle), they have to be in the top as that INFO is about starting the job.

Comment: Can you change the sed command to awk command?
That might work for this problem.

Thanks